# vue js, IE9 click on the router link to refresh?

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-9

vue js
In IE9 (Internet Explorer 9), which does not support the History API pushState, is it correct to refresh on router-link clicks?
Can't you switch pages without refreshing like in Chrome or IE10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check [this article](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) and using  to create anchor tags for declarative navigation.

*You may have noticed that `router.push`, `router.replace` and `router.go` are counterparts of `window.history.pushState`, `window.history.replaceState` and `window.history.go`, and they do imitate the window.history APIs.*